# UISearchTextField design changes only after app enters foreground

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am currently trying to customize the UISearchTextfield. I came across one issue:
The cornerRadius is only applied after the app was sent to the background and brought back to foreground. Am I missing something, that the cornerRadius is also initially applied?

This is my code for customizing:

```
final class TransactionSearchController: UISearchController {
private lazy var customSearchBar = TransactionSearchBar()
override var searchBar: UISearchBar { customSearchBar }

init(colorScheme: ColorScheme) {
    super.init(searchResultsController: nil)
    self.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = true

    self.searchBar.barTintColor = colorScheme.backgroundColor
    self.searchBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.colorWithLight(
        Color.Input.background,
        dark: Color.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
    )
    self.searchBar.searchTextField.borderStyle = .none
    self.searchBar.searchTextField.tintColor = Color.blue
    self.searchBar.searchTextField.leftView?.tintColor = Color.blue
    self.searchBar.searchTextField.font = Font.contentText

    self.searchBar.searchTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0
    self.searchBar.searchTextField.layer.applyShadow(
        offset: CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 6.0),
        radius: 5.0,
        opacity: 0.2
    )
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

}

This method is called in `viewWillAppear` of the parent ViewController. but I also tried it with `viewDidLoad`

Comment: add self.searchBar.searchTextField.layer.maskToBounds = true

Comment: Unfortunately masksToBounds = true does not work

Comment: what does apply shadow? remove the shadow to see if the corner is set alone